# Launch Windows 8.1 and/or Embedded directly into application instead of desktop

Tags: c#, .net, windows, microsoft-metro

We are developing a .NET application (Modern UI). What we wish to do is to launch directly into the Modern UI application, instead of the desktop. We wish to effectively lock the user into our application, which will then be operated through a touch screen.

Is there any way of doing this? Perhaps replace explorer.exe? But this sounds a bit risky and hacky.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Just found this: Windows Embedded 8.1 Lockdown & Branding](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41957)

This seems to do exactly what we need, but we need to use Windows Embedded. Thanks to those who also gave helpful responses!

Answer (score 1):

I found this:
http://winaero.com/blog/exclusive-how-to-start-a-modern-app-from-desktop-without-going-to-the-metro-start-screen/

So, what about to create something like this:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsReadingList_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.WindowsReadingList");
```

This is only idea, but can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can set windows 8.1 into a Kiosk mode, and this will lockdown user into your app.
Go to  Charms->Settings->Change PC Settings->Accounts and you can choose user and application for Kiosk mode.

With this option there is no need for hacks this serves exactly the purpose you need.

Here is detailed info how to setup kiosk mode:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx

Comment: It says that once setup, a user needs to login to the Kiosk mode, requiring user interaction. What we require is to basically hide the fact that we're using Windows.